# Cannot escape a quotation(") character when retriveing a string containg quotation inside a string from DB in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, string, jsp, html-escape-characters

I have saved quotation(") in a string using escape character i database. That is working ok. But when i am retrieving the value in a jsp field from database, the string is being ended at the first quotation it gets in the whole string. I am giving an example below:

Lets take a string that i have stored in database as -

```
" Hello David. This is a "customer"."
```

Now, i am somehow need to save the string back from databse into a hidden field in a jsp page like below-

```
<input type="hidden" name="string_from_database" id="string_from_database" value="<%=some varibale that holds the data from database%>">
```

issue is -
Part of the string is getting exposed (means it is being written on top of the page) which i do not want. In this case,the below phrase is written on the beginning of the jsp page, which i don't want.

```
customer".
```

kindly suggest on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Don't use scriptlet, but [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/).

Comment: Yes you must also escape the contents of attributes.  Most templating languages will do for you. If you use prepared statements it will do the escaping in the sql for you too.  If you use the right tools you don't need to worry about escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Using this function you could replace the quote marks with the html entity variant `&quot;`. Here's a simple function for it. Hope it fits into your templating system, but should be easy to modify if not.

```
function escapeQuotes(str){
    return str.replace(/"/g,'&quot;');
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwtxxyk5/)

Comment: Quote characters are not the only characters that need escaping for HTML attributes. Isn't it better to use a more generic solution such as leaving it up to the templating engine to sort out? There is no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I'd say it does solve OPs specific question, but you are right. You should be using what your template offers you. I'm not familiar jsp or jstl, so I can't really advice or comment on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jstl rather than scriptlets [for further Explanation](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jstl-cout-core-tag/)

use EL - Expression Language (${variable}) to get the Value eg. `${welcome}`

```
<c:out value="${some varibale that holds the data from database}"/>
```